# Deploying two Spring batch applications in same cluster in a single Weblogic Domain?

Tags: java, weblogic, spring-batch, spring-batch-admin

**BackGround -**

I am trying to deploy two spring batch applications as .war in same cluster in a single Weblogic Domain & each of them have spring batch admin console configured in servlet.xml like below -

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

  <!-- Spring Batch Admin -->  
  <import resource="classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml"/>
  <import resource="classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/webapp-config.xml"/>

  <bean id="resourceService" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.web.resources.DefaultResourceService">
    <property name="servletPath" value="/batch" />
  </bean>  

</beans>
```

Its a maven project & spring-batch-admin-manager 1.2.2 is pulled in as dependency.

**Problem -**
I am struggling to get both of them run simultaneously. At the moment I can not have both of them running together, & when i try starting other while one of them is already running I get following error –

```
weblogic.application.ModuleException: [HTTP:######]Servlet: "myServlet" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "myservice-app.war".
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'messageSource' defined in URL [zip:/myservice-app_3.0.0-SNAPSHOT/yvcbfs/war/WEB-INF/lib/spring-batch-admin-manager-1.2.2.RELEASE.jar!/META-INF/spring/batch/servlet/manager/controller-context.xml]: Initialization of bean failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.BatchMBeanExporter@354fd72b] with key 'batchMBeanExporter'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:name=batchMBeanExporter,type=BatchMBeanExporter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:527)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:778)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:457)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1981)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1955)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:149)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mbeanExporter': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.BatchMBeanExporter@354fd72b] with key 'batchMBeanExporter'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:name=batchMBeanExporter,type=BatchMBeanExporter
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1455)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter.collectMBeanExporters(IntegrationMBeanExporter.java:377)
    at org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter.postProcessAfterInitialization(IntegrationMBeanExporter.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    ... 57 more
Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.BatchMBeanExporter@354fd72b] with key 'batchMBeanExporter'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:name=batchMBeanExporter,type=BatchMBeanExporter
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:602)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:527)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterPropertiesSet(MBeanExporter.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    ... 68 more
Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:name=batchMBeanExporter,type=BatchMBeanExporter
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$27.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:714)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.registerMBean(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:709)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXContextInterceptor.registerMBean(JMXContextInterceptor.java:445)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$27.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:712)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.registerMBean(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:709)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.registerMBean(WLSMBeanServer.java:462)
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:655)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:592)
    ... 72 more

    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1520)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:149)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
Caused By: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:name=batchMBeanExporter,type=BatchMBeanExporter
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
    at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
    at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$27.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:714)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.registerMBean(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:709)
    at weblogic.management.mbeanservers.internal.JMXContextInterceptor.registerMBean(JMXContextInterceptor.java:445)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase$27.run(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:712)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.registerMBean(WLSMBeanServerInterceptorBase.java:709)
    at weblogic.management.jmx.mbeanserver.WLSMBeanServer.registerMBean(WLSMBeanServer.java:462)
    at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:169)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:655)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:592)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeans(MBeanExporter.java:527)
    at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.afterPropertiesSet(MBeanExporter.java:413)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1514)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter.collectMBeanExporters(IntegrationMBeanExporter.java:377)
    at org.springframework.integration.monitor.IntegrationMBeanExporter.postProcessAfterInitialization(IntegrationMBeanExporter.java:189)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyBeanPostProcessorsAfterInitialization(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:407)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1461)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:519)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:456)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:294)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:225)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:291)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.initMessageSource(AbstractApplicationContext.java:778)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:457)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:631)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:588)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.createWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:645)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initWebApplicationContext(FrameworkServlet.java:508)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.initServletBean(FrameworkServlet.java:449)
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.HttpServletBean.init(HttpServletBean.java:133)
    at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:241)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:283)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:64)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:58)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:48)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:539)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1981)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1955)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1874)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:3154)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1518)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:484)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:200)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:247)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:425)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:119)
    at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:27)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:671)
    at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:52)
    at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:212)
    at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:44)
    at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:161)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:569)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:150)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:116)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.StartOperation.doCommit(StartOperation.java:149)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:323)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440)
    at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13)
    at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68)
    at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221)
```

As far as I understand, the issue is with spring-batch-admin. Since both the applications are trying to initialize same beans from their configuration I am getting this error, but I don't know how to prevent this from happening.

I have tried searching on stackoverflow & various forums over net but could not find solution to my problem. Can any one please help?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found the solution for this problem. Since it was not able to register the Mbeans we need to override the jmx-context.xml which scans for jmx Mbeans with different domain name.

Create jmx-context.xml in one of your batch project under /META-INF/spring/batch/override/ directory with overridden context:mbean-export for scan & int-jmx:mbean-export for integrating Mbeans like following -

**/META-INF/spring/batch/override/jmx-context.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:int-jmx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx" xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/jmx/spring-integration-jmx.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.0.xsd">

    <int-jmx:mbean-export id="integrationMBeanExporter" default-domain="spring.application.mybatch" server="mbeanServer" />
    <context:mbean-export default-domain="spring.application.mybatch" server="mbeanServer" />
</beans>
```

Make sure that you change the default-domain with unique name for this spring batch project. After implementing this solution I have both the batch applications running simultaneously in single cluster inside Weblogic domain.

It’s important to put jmx-context.xml under /META-INF/spring/batch/override/ as webapp-config.xml you import in your servlet.xml file, for configuring admin console, imports all the *.xml from this override folder & this can be used to override any default configuration. Just for reference I have copied here contents of webapp-config.xml from spring-batch-admin-manager-resources jar which should be pulled in as dependency in your project.

**/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/webapp-config.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd">

    <!-- Workaround for INT-1831 -->
    <bean id="dummy" class="java.util.Date"/>

    <import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/batch/bootstrap/**/*.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath*:/META-INF/spring/batch/override/**/*.xml" />

    <bean id="parameterUnpackerFilter" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.web.filter.ParameterUnpackerFilter">
        <property name="prefix" value="unpack_"/>
        <property name="putEmptyParamsInPath" value="true"/>
    </bean>

</beans>
```

Just in case if you are wondering where we import this webapp-config.xml, I have put down the contents of servlet.xml for configuring batch admin console, which you load on start-up in web.xml of your project.

**/WEB-INF/config/spring-beans/servlet.xml -**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd">

    <!-- Spring Batch Admin -->  
    <import resource="classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/servlet-config.xml"/>
    <import resource="classpath*:/org/springframework/batch/admin/web/resources/webapp-config.xml"/>

    <bean id="resourceService" class="org.springframework.batch.admin.web.resources.DefaultResourceService">
        <property name="servletPath" value="/batch" />
    </bean>  

</beans>
```