# javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:type=JobExecution,name=DATSFileFeeds

Tags: spring-batch

I am trying to deploy two wars in a single tomcat server instance. but it is throwing errors. can anyone please help in this. PFB the error log.

> 19:39:28,294 ERROR pool-2-thread-1 context.ContextLoader:220 - Context initialization failed
>   org.springframework.context.ApplicationContextException: Failed to start bean 'batchMBeanExporter'; nested exception is org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.SimpleJobExecutionMetrics@1f069c] with key 'spring.application:type=JobExecution,name=DATSFileFeeds'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:type=JobExecution,name=DATSFileFeeds
>       at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:169)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.access$1(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:154)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor$LifecycleGroup.start(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:335)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.startBeans(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:143)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.onRefresh(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:108)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishRefresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:908)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:428)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.createWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:276)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:197)
>       at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:47)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
>       at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:897)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:873)
>       at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:615)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:958)
>       at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig$DeployWar.run(HostConfig.java:1599)
>       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
>       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:744)
>   Caused by: org.springframework.jmx.export.UnableToRegisterMBeanException: Unable to register MBean [org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.SimpleJobExecutionMetrics@1f069c] with key 'spring.application:type=JobExecution,name=DATSFileFeeds'; nested exception is javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:type=JobExecution,name=DATSFileFeeds
>       at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:602)
>       at org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.BatchMBeanExporter.registerJobs(BatchMBeanExporter.java:190)
>       at org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.BatchMBeanExporter.doStart(BatchMBeanExporter.java:353)
>       at org.springframework.batch.admin.jmx.BatchMBeanExporter.start(BatchMBeanExporter.java:307)
>       at org.springframework.context.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor.doStart(DefaultLifecycleProcessor.java:166)
>       ... 22 more
>   Caused by: javax.management.InstanceAlreadyExistsException: spring.application:type=JobExecution,name=DATSFileFeeds
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.Repository.addMBean(Repository.java:437)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerWithRepository(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:1898)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerDynamicMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:966)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerObject(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:900)
>       at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.registerMBean(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:324)
>       at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.registerMBean(JmxMBeanServer.java:522)
>       at org.springframework.jmx.support.MBeanRegistrationSupport.doRegister(MBeanRegistrationSupport.java:169)
>       at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanInstance(MBeanExporter.java:655)
>       at org.springframework.jmx.export.MBeanExporter.registerBeanNameOrInstance(MBeanExporter.java:598)
>       ... 26 more

Comment: i also tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24613538/deploying-two-spring-batch-applications-in-same-cluster-in-a-single-weblogic-dom

Comment: After searching far and wide I found a solution for my version of this problem with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28295503/migration-to-tomcat-8-instancealreadyexistsexception-datasource and wanted to point any wayward, lost soul in that direction.

Answer (score 5):

You can configure the behavior for MBean registration using [MBeanRegistrationSupport#setRegistrationPolicy](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api//org/springframework/jmx/support/MBeanRegistrationSupport.html#setRegistrationPolicy-org.springframework.jmx.support.RegistrationPolicy-) method.

Currently there are three policies:

1. FAIL_ON_EXISTING - Registration should fail when attempting to
   register an MBean under a name that already exists.
2. IGNORE_EXISTING - Registration should ignore the affected MBean when attempting to register an MBean under a name that already
   exists.
3. REPLACE_EXISTING - Registration should replace the affected MBean when attempting to register an MBean under a name that already
   exists.

For example:

```
@Bean
public AnnotationMBeanExporter annotationMBeanExporter() {
    AnnotationMBeanExporter annotationMBeanExporter = new AnnotationMBeanExporter();
    annotationMBeanExporter.setRegistrationPolicy(RegistrationPolicy.IGNORE_EXISTING);

    return annotationMBeanExporter;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can register the MBean conditionally:

```
//Get the MBean server
MBeanServer mbs = ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer();
//register the MBean
number = new NumberOfSomething();
ObjectName name = new ObjectName("ru.pochta.abon.mbean:type=NumberOfSomething");
if (!mbs.isRegistered(name)) {
    mbs.registerMBean(number, name);
}
```